# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function player.cueVideoById

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, youtube-api

I want to create one web player using youtube player api. I want to create auto play video.

For that I used following script:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

        var player;
        var isPlaying = false;

        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '420',
                width: '640',
                playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0, 'showinfo': 0 },
                events: {
                    //  'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
        }

        function onPlayerReady(event) {
            event.target.playVideo();
        }


        var done = false;
        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
                setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
                done = true;
            }
        }

        function stopPlayerVideo() {
            player.stopVideo();
            return false;
        }
        function playPlayerVideo() {
            player.playVideo();
            return false;
        }
        function pausePlayerVideo() {
            player.pauseVideo();
            return false;
        }

        function ShowModalPopup() {
            var url = $get("<%=hfURL.ClientID %>").value;                   
            if (url != "") {
                var fn = function () {
                    if(player != null)
                        $('#txtCnt').val(cnt + " : " + isPlaying + " :u " + url);
                    player.cueVideoById(url, 0, "hd1440");
                    player.playVideo();
                    $('#msg').hide();
                    $('#img_msg').hide();
                    isPlaying = true;
                    pendingDate = new Date();
                    pendingSec = 0;
                }
                setTimeout(fn, 1000);
                $get("<%=hfDuration.ClientID %>").value = "";
                $find("mpe").show();
            }
            return false;
        }        

        function GetPlayTimeDuration() {
            player.stopVideo();
            player.clearVideo();
            $get("<%=hfDuration.ClientID %>").value = $('#time').val();
            //$find("mpe").hide();

            if ($get("<%=hfDuration.ClientID %>").value == "") {
                $get("<%=hfDuration.ClientID %>").value = "0";
            }

            isPlaying = false;
            $('#time').val("");
            $get("<%=hfURL.ClientID %>").value = "";

            var UpdatePanel1 = '<%=upSubmit.ClientID%>';            
            if (UpdatePanel1 != null) {
                __doPostBack('<%= btnClose.ClientID %>', '');
            }

        }

        var cnt = 0;
        setInterval(function () {
            if (player != null) {
                if (isPlaying) {
                    player.setPlaybackQuality('hd1440');
                    var tmptime = player.getCurrentTime();
                    tmptime = tmptime - ($('#<%= hfTimeFrame.ClientID %>').val() * tmptime);
                    $('#time').val(tmptime);

                    if (parseFloat($('#<%= hfCutoff.ClientID %>').val()) < parseFloat($('#time').val()))
                        GetPlayTimeDuration();

                }
                else if (!isPlaying) {
                    if ($get("<%=hfURL.ClientID %>").value != "") {
                        ShowModalPopup();
                    }
                }

                cnt++;                
            }
            else {
                player = new YT.Player('player', {
                    height: '420',
                    width: '640',
                    playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0, 'showinfo': 0 },
                    events: {
                        //  'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                    }
                });                
            }
        }, 10);
```

my problem is that some time it so error:

> *Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function player.cueVideoById*

Comment: In what line do you get the error?

Comment: player.cueVideoById(url, 0, "hd1440");

Answer (score 0):

`"hd1440"` is not one of the valid values you can set as the playback quality for `cueVideoById`. According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=en#setPlaybackQuality), the possible values are:

> - small
> - medium
> - large
> - hd720
> - hd1080
> - highres
> - default

In addition, the YouTube JavaScript Player API has been deprecated as of this year, so I wouldn't expect it to work the way you think it should.